# CPP : using different sign instead of hash '#' for directives?

Tags: c-preprocessor

Is there a way to use different sign in place of hash-sign # for specifying directives ?

may be specified when running it via cmd line param ..

Answer (score 0):

The C preprocessor unambiguously uses `#` to indicate directives. No standard implementation allows this to be changed.

Even a non-standard preprocessor must be at least somewhat aware of C lexical syntax, on order to avoid expanding macros inside comments and strings. It also must correctly handle the `#` and `##` preprocessor operators. So modifying the sigil character is likely to be an intrusive change. There are open source preprocessor libraries available if you want to give it a try.